# Curl request with post params

Tags: php, json, curl, encoding

I have been trying to send a curl request with the below post params contained within `$postData` and it does not seem to work. Has anybody been able to accomplish this? I appreciate any suggestions.

```
$postData = '{"paramCollection":[{"param":{"PrdNo":-1,"Type":"H2H","RequestType":"Normal","H2HParam":{"Lv1":"Baseball","Lv2":"MLB"}}}]}:';

$ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
```

Comment: two things check for curl errors. and increase your timeout

Comment: you have to unserialize it before or after

Comment: @Motsim, executing `unserialize()` on the above string returns false

Answer (score -1):

Tested your example and it seems to work fine, maybe the server you want to POST, requires you to have the correct Content-Type header to be set. So it knows you are sending json data.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  [                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',
]);
```

You aren't forgetting: `curl_exec($ch)`, right?

Comment: I appreciate the help, however, this made no difference, same exact output when doing `curl_exec($ch)`

Comment: Hmm, what happens if you send the request with, for example postman?

Comment: The requests works you only get a 302 as response code, redirecting you to a error page. My guess is that you needed to be logged in before you can access that page, not sure though.